# Angular 7 import all but ignore one file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, import

I'm using C3 in an Angular 7 project and I'm importing all the files at the top of my .ts component file using the wildcard

`import * as c3 from 'c3';`

which works great until I realize all my CSS overrides are being imported waaaay before the C3 package's c3.min.css gets imported so all my overrides are not used. Is there a way to include everything but one file ?

Or do I have to go through and import every file associated to C3 manually? I know I could use the components SCSS file, but my overrides are kind of in a bootstrap-esq package.

Comment: on your angular.json file use the "styles": [] array to set the priority

Comment: My CSS overrides are being imported in the angular.json. The C3 styles are getting imported through the component using the import at the top of the component so there is no way to change the order. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a function of Typescript modules (which Angular is using).

Unfortunately there is no "wildcard minus something" functionality.

Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

or: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/project/external-modules.html

Comment: Ahhhh yes, you're totally right. I've updated the tags to include Typescript thanks to another edit suggestion. Thank you for your links! I saw there was a github forum that got closed before the answer got submitted.